# predict.glmnet() gives same predictions for type = "link" and "response" using family = "binomial"

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

Take this case (classic crab data for logistic regression):

```
> library(glmnet)
> X <- read.table("http://www.da.ugent.be/datasets/crab.dat", header=T)[1:10,]
> Y <- factor(ifelse(X$Sa > 0, 1, 0))
> Xnew <- data.frame('W'=20,'Wt'=2000)
> fit.glmnet <- glmnet(x = data.matrix(X[,c('W','Wt')]), y = Y, family = "binomial")
```

Now I want to predict new values from `Xnew`:

According to the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf) I can use `predict.glmnet`:

> type
>
> Type of prediction required. Type "link" gives the linear predictors
>   for "binomial", "multinomial", "poisson" or "cox" models; for
>   "gaussian" models it gives the fitted values. Type "response" gives
>   the fitted probabilities for "binomial" or "multinomial", [...]

So this is what I do:

```
> predict.glmnet(object = fit.glmnet, type="response", newx = as.matrix(Xnew))[,1:5]
        s0         s1         s2         s3         s4 
-0.8472979 -0.9269763 -1.0057390 -1.0836919 -1.1609386 
> predict.glmnet(object = fit.glmnet, type="link", newx = as.matrix(Xnew))[,1:5]
        s0         s1         s2         s3         s4 
-0.8472979 -0.9269763 -1.0057390 -1.0836919 -1.1609386
```

Same values for both `link` as `response` predictions, which is not what I expect. Using `predict` seems to give me the correct values:

```
> predict(object = fit.glmnet, type="response", newx = as.matrix(Xnew))[,1:5]
       s0        s1        s2        s3        s4 
0.3000000 0.2835386 0.2678146 0.2528080 0.2384968 
> predict(object = fit.glmnet, type="link", newx = as.matrix(Xnew))[,1:5] 
        s0         s1         s2         s3         s4 
-0.8472979 -0.9269763 -1.0057390 -1.0836919 -1.1609386
```

**Is this a bug, or am I using `predict.glmnet` in a wrong way?**

Comment: Check the class of your fitted model, then read the code for `predict.lognet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the packet `glmnet`, your object is of class `lognet`:

```
> class(object)
[1] "lognet" "glmnet"
```

That's why you are not getting the right result with `predict.glmnet`, which internally does not support `type="response"`, but you will get it if you use `predict.lognet`:

```
> predict.lognet(object = fit.glmnet, newx = as.matrix(Xnew), type="response")[,1:5]
       s0        s1        s2        s3        s4 
0.3000000 0.2835386 0.2678146 0.2528080 0.2384968 
> predict.lognet(object = fit.glmnet, newx = as.matrix(Xnew), type="link")[,1:5]
        s0         s1         s2         s3         s4 
-0.8472979 -0.9269763 -1.0057390 -1.0836919 -1.1609386
```

Anyway I would recommend you that you use `predict`, and let R resolve internally which function to use.

Hope it helps.